# How to generate conformations for a ligand for in silico screening?

Tags: pdb

I have multiple ligands (in pdb format) which I want to try and dock to various proteins.

But for each ligand I have only a single conformation (by which I meant the spatial relationship between it's atoms, not its position relative to the target protein).

How do I generate other possible conformations?
Is there a generally used tool for that?

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by “pose”. You need to use standard scientific English on this site.  Do you mean structure? If not it shouldn’t be difficult to find a scientific paper that uses the correct term.

Comment: Thanks.
I see that these are properly referred to as conformations.

Comment: Ok. I assume that your ligands are peptides or proteins that can adopt different conformations. There may be software for doing this, but it will be quite sophisticated. Good luck.

Comment: I'm going to migrate this because it's a better fit for Bioinformatics since it's about tools rather than the underlying biology, and I think you're more likely to get a good answer there. I'm only loosely aware of their policies there so you may need to make edits.

Comment: @David ["Pose" is standard scientific English for macromolecular docking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docking_(molecular)).

Comment: @canadianer — I stand corrected, although wonder how many on this list are familiar with the term.

Answer (score 1):

One option I found was Frog2

https://mobyle.rpbs.univ-paris-diderot.fr/cgi-bin/portal.py#forms::Frog2

https://github.com/tuffery/Frog2

From an input of a `mol2` or `sdf` file it creates a plethora of conformers, which can be outputted as a `pdb` file

Answer (score 1):

### Open babel

The most commonly used tool is `open-babel` (obabel). It seems annoying that you have to specify the number of conformers, but this is because if you get something like retinol, the number of conformers is huge. The command from the [documentation](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3DStructureGen/multipleconformers.html) is:

```
obabel startingConformer.mol -O ga_conformers.sdf --conformer --nconf 30
   --score rmsd --writeconformers
```

An alternative argument is `--confab` which will pick each representative of a RMSD cutoff cluster.

Do note that 2D representations and un-protonated molecules will need extra command line arguments.

### RDKit

You can also generate conformers in RDkit, but I think this is beyond your requirements, but I thought it may be good to mention the essential compchem python library.